Metabase error when connecting to SQL Server 2016, happens on RHEL9 but not on RHEL7, why?
We are testing an upgraded instance of Metabase, and the upgraded components include

RHEL (from v7 to v9) operating system,
Java (from 11 to 21), and
Metabase software (from v0.32.x to v0.50.x as the current).

And we noticed the following error in the upgraded instance when connecting to a data source of SQL Server 2016.

"encrypt" property is set to "false" and "trustServerCertificate" property is set to "false" but the driver could not establish a secure connection to SQL Server by using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) encryption: Error: Certificates do not conform to algorithm constraints. ClientConnectionId:6bf62750-d5c4-49c5-8ada-4253d8b55055

We suspect the error is related to the system behavior of RHEL9, therefore we designed the following simplified test case to support our point:
Test configuration:

Java openjdk v11.0.23
metabase.jar v0.32.5

We start the application by calling command java -jar metabase.jar, so it starts a fresh demonstration instance of Metabase running on local H2 for application database.
Then, we try to add a data source of SQL Server 2016 configured with encryption not required.
Running on RHEL7, the above test succeeded. However, running on RHEL9, it failed with the following log events, notice the timestamp of 12-19 14:58:44:
12-19 14:58:09 DEBUG middleware.log :: GET /api/setup/admin_checklist 200 14 ms (10 DB calls) Jetty threads: 8/50 (3 busy, 5 idle, 0 queued) (48 total active threads)
12-19 14:58:44 INFO metabase.driver :: Initializing driver :sqlserver...
12-19 14:58:44 DEBUG plugins.classloader :: Setting current thread context classloader to shared classloader clojure.lang.DynamicClassLoader@1dc9fc0...
12-19 14:58:44 INFO plugins.classloader :: Added URL file:/data/metabase-test/v0.32.5/plugins/sqlserver.metabase-driver.jar to classpath
12-19 14:58:44 DEBUG plugins.init-steps :: Loading plugin namespace metabase.driver.sqlserver...
12-19 14:58:44 INFO metabase.driver :: Registered driver :sqlserver (parents: :sql-jdbc) 
12-19 14:58:44 DEBUG plugins.jdbc-proxy :: Registering JDBC proxy driver for class com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver...
Load lazy loading driver :sqlserver took 173 ms
12-19 14:58:44 DEBUG middleware.log :: POST /api/database 400 314 ms (0 DB calls) Jetty threads: 8/50 (3 busy, 4 idle, 0 queued) (45 total active threads)
{:valid false,
 :dbname
 "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The driver could not establish a secure connection to SQL Server by using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) encryption. Error: \"Certificates do not conform to algorithm constraints\". ClientConnectionId:ca179b99-b3b3-4351-a0de-736b7dc8e765",
 :message
 "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The driver could not establish a secure connection to SQL Server by using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) encryption. Error: \"Certificates do not conform to algorithm constraints\". ClientConnectionId:ca179b99-b3b3-4351-a0de-736b7dc8e765"}

12-19 14:58:44 DEBUG middleware.log :: GET /api/database 200 5 ms (3 DB calls) Jetty threads: 8/50 (3 busy, 4 idle, 0 queued) (45 total active threads)
12-19 15:00:00 INFO task.send-pulses :: Sending scheduled pulses...

We wonder if we missed anything with regard to the new operating system, and we highly appreciate any pointers and hints.
